# Loops/timers in C

Tags: c, linux, loops, timer

How does one create a timer in C?

I want a piece of code to continuously fetch data from a gps parsers output.

Are there good libraries for this or should it be self written?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? How are you parsing the output? It's really difficult to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Dont worry about the parsing. I would just like to know how to create a timer function in C which loops and executes its statements.

Comment: Based on later comments, added Linux to the tags

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simplest method available:

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *do_smth_periodically(void *data)
{
  int interval = *(int *)data;
  for (;;) {
    do_smth();
    usleep(interval);
  }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread;
  int interval = 5000;

  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, do_smth_periodically, &interval)

  ...
}
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but he did also mention that he wanted it run in a separate thread, so the code to create a thread and run `do_smth_periodically()` in it would also be helpful. Also, this method will cause the entire "wall" time of the loop to vary depending on how much time it takes to do `do_smth()` each iteration. Most likely that's fine for his application though.

Comment: Race condition warning: Be careful to keep `interval` variable in memory when calling `pthread_create` from another function instead of `main()`, because `interval` may become out of scope before the thread assignment of `*data` argument in the first line.

Answer (score 8):

On POSIX systems you can create (and catch) an [alarm](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm).  Alarm is simple but set in seconds.  If you need finer resolution than seconds then use [setitimer](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer).

```
struct itimerval tv;
tv.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
tv.it_interval.tv_usec = 100000;  // when timer expires, reset to 100ms
tv.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
tv.it_value.tv_usec = 100000;   // 100 ms == 100000 us
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tv, NULL);
```

And catch the timer on a regular interval by setting [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction).

Answer (score 4):

One doesn't "create a timer in C". There is nothing about timing or scheduling in the C standard, so how that is accomplished is left up to the Operating System.

This is probably a reasonable question for a C noob, as many languages *do* support things like this. Ada does, and I believe the next version of C++ will probably do so (Boost has support for it now). I'm pretty sure Java can do it too.

On linux, probably the best way would be to use [pthread](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads)s. In particular, you need to call [pthread_create()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) and pass it the address of your routine, which presumably contains a loop with a [sleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) (or [usleep()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep)) call at the bottom.

Note that if you want to do something that approximates real-time scheduling, just doing a dumb `usleep()` isn't good enough because it won't account for the execution time of the loop itself. For those applications you will need to set up a [periodic timer](http://linux.die.net/man/3/timer) and wait on that.

Comment: So how would I execute a function in a loop in its own thread?

Comment: @Helium3 - Either use OS calls (which depend on what OS you are running, which you have yet to tell us), or use a better language.

Comment: It will be run on Ubuntu on a Pandaboard.

Comment: [pedantic] a 'better' language is defined by having timing support? funny.

Comment: @stijn - For this particular purpose, yes a language that has actual support for threading (even in a portable library like boost) would be better. C has its stregths too, but this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/index.php) provides a cross platform timer in C.

http://www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_AddTimer

Comment: It appears to be a framework designed around multimedia. He'd have to use its "mainloop" and set up a timer callback. Could be useful, if that kind of structure is acceptable.

Comment: @T.E.D. It is designed for multimedia, but I've found its timers and its event queue to be handy on their own.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Windows, you can use [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),else you can build a timer out of `timeGetTime` and `_beginthreadex` along with a queue of timers with callbacks

Answer (score 0):

The question about a timer is quite unspecific, though there are two functions that come to my mind that will help you:

- sleep() This function will cause execution to stop for a specified number of seconds. You can also use usleep and nanosleep if you want to specify the sleeptime more exactly
- gettimeofday() Using this function you are able to stop between to timesteps.

See manpages for further explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

If the gps data is coming from some hardware device, like over a serial port, then one thing that you may consider is changing the architecture around so that the parser kicks off the code that you are trying to run when more data is available.

It could do this through a callback function or it could send an event - the actual implementation would depend on what you have available.