# Invoke function at future time

Tags: c, linux, gcc, posix

In a long-running server program (built in C) in a Posix (Linux) environment:  what is the best approach to get a **function to execute at a specific time in the future**?  It doesn't need to execute in any particular thread, but the accuracy of the execution time needs to be a few milliseconds.  General approaches or specific code is appreciated.

Comment: Wrap it in `int main()` and a cron job?

Comment: @H2CO3 cron does not have millisecond resolution

Comment: The program is a server that is running the whole time. I will update the question.

Comment: I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540245/loops-timers-in-c

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer looks helpful.

Comment: Do you want to execute it AT a specific absolute time or relative to some event?

Comment: @brooks94: There are two possible meanings to "millisecond accuracy" here. 1) Given a time `t`, execute some code within milliseconds of `t`. 2) Given a time `t`, execute some code "sometime quite shortly after `t`" and be able to tell with millisecond precision how much you overshot `t`. The latter is much easier than the former.

Comment: @Sascha at a specific absolute time

Comment: @brooks94: If at a specific absolute time, what happens if that time never occurs? Maybe somebody set the clock ahead. Are you sure you don't want to execute at some *relative* time (like "an hour after the program started").

Comment: The `pthreads` code in @AndrewWhite's linked answer should work if you take out the loop and calculate the right sleep time based on desired execution time.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt is another alternative , wait for rtc alarm just a second before, then launch a thread to wait for the exact millisecond. The advantage is that you don't have to deal with changes in time.

Answer (score 1):

There are some high resolution clock functions in the GNU C library (`sys/timex.h`), so although they are not POSIX, they will be portable linux wise.

[High Accuracy Clock -- The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/High-Accuracy-Clock.html)

Those functions are prefixed 'ntp' although they do not require or make use of any ntp service, so the relationship is purely superficial.

Beware that although the granularity is in microseconds, the linux kernel has a userspace latency of 10ms so don't bother or expect anything more accurate than that.

Once you have the current high resolution time, you could then calculate a duration and use (posix) [nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) (but again, round to 10ms) to set a delay.   There is also a [clock_nanosleep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html) which might be of interest.

Comment: OS X and some other systems (Solaris, exceptional BSD variants, etc.) also use GNU libc, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Though the "few milliseconds" could be achieved with RT patching the kernel. I don't know how much control brooks94 has over the platform he/she is working on. It's sounding like they need quite a lot!

Comment: I understand how this allows me to see what time it is, but how do I execute something at a specific time?  I'm interested in the details of the threads and data structures I would need to make it work.

Comment: @brooks94 : You would need to calculate a specific delay based on the current time; use `nanosleep`.  I added a brief paragraph with links for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up posix timers. It gives you a simple interface to scheduling future work. You can manage it to send you a signal in x seconds/ nanoseconds (ad then you can put your function as it's signal handler). Lookup timer_create