# How to create a timer that remove a 1 from variable from per seconds

Tags: c

I have created a simple timer that counts up in seconds/minutes.

I wish for every seconds it will minus like 1 (-- or -= 1) from a variables per seconds. Can you give some guidelines on the logic how would I program this. As my seconds only ranges from 0-60 and i wish the countdown can go indefinitely and also doesn't rely on the int p.

I have already have working function that can grab the current computer clock time let called it

Codes that works (minutes/seconds are global variable.)

```
    double clock = get_time() - start_time;
    minutes = abs(clock/60);
    seconds = clock - (minutes * 60);
```

x is a global variable.

```
int p;
x = p -(seconds);
```

Comment: It all depends on a platform you're coding for.

Comment: It just basic C, on linux.

Comment: Would adding delays help you? Such as "sleep(1); x -= 1;" inside a loop. When the time spent for the code to run is added to the delay (1 sec) it exceeds 1 sec but im not sure if substracting 1 from a variable will take any significant amount of time.

Comment: @Bondspencil By platform I mean a hardware. Is it x86(64) or something other? Linux could be ran on a numerous devices.

Comment: x86 on Intel CPU(7th gen). 6 @montonero

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540245/loops-timers-in-c)

Comment: Maybe I didn't catch the original problem, but why to use a timer for counting seconds? A clock is much better tool for that.

Comment: This may be true, but timer seem to use way more CPU compare to using system_clocktime. @SKi

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little snippet that waits roughly 1 second between each print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t clock = time(NULL);
    int total = 0;
    int interval = 1;
    while (total < 20) {
        time_t cur = time(NULL);
        if (cur - clock > interval) {
            total++;
            printf("one sec passed\n");
            clock = cur;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can implement small sleeps between each interation.

Comment: Sure I can, but what's about OP?

Comment: Yeah this use way too much CPU, I hoping using the start_time and current_time variables to calculate time passed.